# Removing Add To Cart from WooCommerce Loop only on one product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to remove the add to cart button only from product in the product loop and add some text instead.

The following code does remove the button, but also from all buttons after the condition has been validated:

```
function remove_purchase_buttons_from_loop() {

if( $product->id == $_product->id ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',  'level_already_in_cart_notice', 10 );
       }
```

}

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'remove_purchase_buttons_from_loop'));
```

I understand why this happening but what is the right solution

Comment: why you want to replace the text from button? are you going to down the store?

Comment: No, I want to prevent from customer the option to purchase specific products based on purchase history or based on the product in the cart.

In single product view everything is working great the problem that I have is only in the product loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(is_single()) {
  function remove_purchase_buttons_from_loop() {

     if( $product->id == $_product->id ) {
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
         add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',  'level_already_in_cart_notice', 10 );
       }
   }
   add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'remove_purchase_buttons_from_loop'));
} else {
   // your code
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but how can this solve it? can you please put the full code include mine also as I see in both single and no single the same code is running.

Comment: just use if(is_single()) { // wrap your code } and wrap your code in this condition in functions.php